# Android - using a button to change the screen's brightness

Tags: java, android, brightness, screen-brightness

```
int BrightnesValue= 0;
        try {
            BrightnesValue = Settings.System.getInt(
                    getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int SysBackLightValue = BrightnesValue-25;
        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                SysBackLightValue);
```

I want to change the system's brightness programmatically using a button on the toolbar as shown in the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSsfu.png). Such that, when clicked for the first time, the brightness reduces, when clicked a second time, the brightness is restored to default.

Comment: Please post your code. We won't be any help until we see where you went wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can set screen BRIGHTNESS button click

**FIRST WAY:**

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int curBrightnessValue=android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
       getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
   setBrightness(curBrightnessValue-25);//set BRIGHTNESS
  }
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {  
    try {  
      IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(  
      ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));  
      if (hardware != null) {  
        hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);  
      }  
    } catch (RemoteException doe) {            
    }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST"></uses-permission>
```

**SECOND WAY:**

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   int curBrightnessValue=android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
   getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
   int SysBackLightValue = curBrightnessValue-25;
   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
   android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
   SysBackLightValue);
  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: in public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) function